# How can I manage my Delicious bookmarks in Firefox 28 and later?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, delicious

I used to manage my bookmarks with the help of [Delicious](https://delicious.com/) but recently I have encountered a problem. After a Firefox update, I noticed that my previous extension won't work anymore and when I checked the [add-on developer's site](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/delicious-bookmarks/) I found out they will not support this add-on anymore.

How can I use Delicious bookmarking in Firefox? (to bookmark some site or find my previous bookmarked site with help of their tag).

Answer (score 1):

I have finally had it with there being no replacement for the "really delicious" addon from the old days you speak of.  Not only has the old addon that I have kept running finally gone to a state of too many bugs, after days of searching I didn't find anything close to what was offered by it before (on any browser!).

**So I decided to take it upon myself to create something similar.**
[Here is my new project about it.](http://attic.e-motiv.net/ff-delicious)
Currently only a toolbar tags-dropdown though, very soon a migration guide and later a sidebar.

I hope you are one of the fellows who remember the "good times" and I am not too late with all this. I fear most people might have given up earlier.

Answer (score 0):

They've created a new [Firefox Social API Extension](https://delicious.com/tools):

> Delicious for Firefox offers a native Delicious save button and sidebar for Firefox. (Click "Share This Page" from toolbar to open the save dialog.)

Comment: it's not working properly  (at least for me)  I liked previous extension more than this API :(